# How to copy the lower part of the lanes of a XMM register with libsimdpp

Tags: sse, intrinsics

I'm using [libsimdpp](https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp) to write vectorized code. It seems that I cannot find a way to move less than all the lanes from memory or from a register to another register.

For example, with the `_mm_move_sd` or _`mm_move_ss` intrinsics (`movsd` or `movss` opcodes) one can copy the lowest one or two lanes between registers, leaving the other lanes intact.

How do you do the same with libsimdpp?

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the libsimdpp library, but as far as I can see you can use `simdpp::shuffle2x2`, with suitable permutation indices, as an alternative to `_mm_move_sd`. From the file https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp/blob/master/simdpp/detail/insn/shuffle2x2.h, we can see that in this way `_mm_shuffle_pd` or `_mm_blend_pd` is used, depending on the permutation indices which are chosen. These Intel intrinsics can be used as an alternative to `_mm_move_sd`.

From the [manual page](https://p12tic.github.io/libsimdpp/v2.2-dev/libsimdpp/w/shuffle/shuffle2x2.html) it seems that you have to choose the permutation indices `s0 = 2`, and `s1 = 1` to emulate `_mm_move_sd`. This corresponds to
line 156 and 157 of `shuffle2x2.h`, which is: `if (s0 == 2 && s1 == 1) {return _mm_blend_pd(b.native(), a.native(), 0x2);}`.

---

An alternative for `_mm_move_ss` is `_mm_blend_ps`, with a suitable mask. With `simdpp::shuffle4x2` the libsimdpp library chooses `_mm_blend_ps` on the x86 architecture, if the following is true for the permutation indices `(s0==0 || s0==4) && (s1==1 || s1==5) && (s2==2 || s2==6) && (s3==3 || s3==7)`, see [sse_float32_4x2.h](https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp/blob/master/simdpp/detail/shuffle/sse_float32_4x2.h), line 40 and 155.

Note that, for example, GCC may compile both `_mm_blend_ps(a, b, 1)`, and `_mm_move_ss` to the `movss` instruction. See [this Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/9-2vl9). So, with libsimdpp and a smart compiler, indeed it is possible to generate the `movss` opcode.
But note that only `_mm_blend_pd(a, b, 1);` is recognized by GCC, not
`_mm_blend_pd(a, b, 2);`, which is produced by libsimdpp.

Note that the `blendpd/ps` instruction with register operands has better throughput than `movsd/ss`, on Intel CPUs since the Intel Haswell processor, as Peter Cordes remarked in his comment.

Comment: `blendpd` has better throughput (any port on HSW) than `movss xmx,xmm` (port 5 only on NHM and later); that's a silly deoptimization by gcc for `-march=haswell`.  Maybe gcc introduced that for code-size back in Core2 days and never re-checked it :/

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed it is good to note that the `blendps/ps` instructions have better performance on modern cpu's than the `movsd/ss` instructions on modern cpu's.

Comment: Right, for register-to-register, shuffle can basically do any type of move. But what about memory-to-register? Say I need to load lanes 0 and 1 from two consecutive floats in memory, zeroing out lanes 2 and 3. Wouldn't `_mm_move_sd` do that in one single instruction?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify - `_mm_move_sd` appears to only move between registers, I really mean  `_mm_load_sd` then.

Comment: Indeed `_mm_move_sd` and `_mm_load_sd` both compile to the `movsd` instruction, and `_mm_load_sd` loads 64 bits from memory and zeroes the upper 64 bits. Intrinsic `_mm_load_sd` compiles to only one instruction, while a load+blend may compile to 2 instructions, which is less efficient, obviously. However, it turns out that the Clang compiler is 
able to recognize the pattern of some specific load+blend-s and generates the same single instruction `(v)movsd`. See [this Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/vjD4WF). 
The output of the GCC (8.2) compiler, with the same code, is less efficient.

Comment: According to Agner Fog's [instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) 
the `movsd` instruction, with memory load operand, is is only one micro-op, while `blendps`, 
with memory operand, is 2 micro-ops. This confirms that the `movsd` instruction is preferable.


It seems to me that libsimdpp is great for portability, but Intel intrinsics
give you more opportunities to write the most efficient code.